# Stored Procedures in BigQuery

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

Can anyone help me with this stored procedure problem. My SP is not giving me the answer within my input dates. What am I doing wrong here?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `PROJECT.DATASET.Test1`(datefrom DATE, dateto DATE)
BEGIN
    Create or Replace Table `PROJECT.DATASET.Test1` AS 
    SELECT *
    FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.VIEW_1` --This is a view
    WHERE calendar_date = calendar_date;
END;
```

When I call my procedure:

```
DECLARE datefrom DATE DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE dateto DATE DEFAULT NULL;
CALL `PROJECT.DATASET.Test1`('2020-08-01', '2020-08-10');
```

By the way, I am new at stackoverflow and if you don't like my question please tell and give me a chance to improve my question rather then flagging.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing to use your input dates in WHERE clause
Consider fixing your proc as per below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test1(datefrom DATE, dateto DATE) 
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `PROJECT.DATASET.Result_TABLE` AS
  SELECT *
  FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.VIEW_1` --This is a view
  WHERE calendar_date BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto;
END;
```

After proc is fixed - now you can use below to see result

```
DECLARE datefrom DATE DEFAULT NULL; 
DECLARE dateto DATE DEFAULT NULL; 
CALL `PROJECT.DATASET.Test1`('2020-08-01', '2020-08-10');
SELECT * FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.Result_TABLE`;
```